# AMDGPU-Pro driver won't load into kernel on Sea Islands / Kabini on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I installed the AMDGPU-Pro driver following the instructions from AMD. Kernel shows neither 'AMDGPU-Pro' nor the original 'radeon' driver "in use" but does show they are available.

[Screenshot: The module is installed but not running on the kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPrLW.png)

I also followed [the instructions](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-413-gcn101&num=1) from the following article to ensure that the driver will load on Kabini / Sea Islands but that still didn't help:

> So basically if you want to get AMDGPU working for Sea Islands and Southern Islands GPUs on Linux 4.13+, you need to append "radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1" to your kernel command line when booting the system.

How do I get my kernel to use the driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:
Ditch AMDGPU-Pro for KABINI and go with the Radeon driver ("radeondriver"). OpenGL acceleration is provided with radeon driver **despite not having a visible libGL**.